# SQL> Combine two select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

**1**

```
SELECT v.NAME,
  CASE 
    WHEN va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois'
      THEN 'Illinois'
    END Vendors
FROM grocery.vendor v
INNER JOIN grocery.vendor_address va ON va.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
WHERE va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois';
```

**2**

```
SELECT vendor_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN count(DISTINCT product_id) > 2
      THEN 'High'
    END
FROM grocery.can_supply
HAVING count(DISTINCT product_id) > 2
GROUP BY vendor_id
ORDER BY vendor_id;
```

The question I have to try and answer is:
What are the full names of all vendors who can supply more than one item or are based in Illinois?

I know how to write them separately, but I need to write them together and it is puzzling me.

EDITED

I tried to UNION and it gave me this error:

> *
>   ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

```
SQL> SELECT vc.contact_name,
       CASE
         WHEN va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois'
           THEN 'Availible' 
       END CheckAvail
     FROM grocery.vendor_address va 
     INNER JOIN grocery.vendor_contact vc ON vc.vendor_id = va.vendor_id 
     WHERE va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois' union select vc.contact_name
         CASE
            WHEN count(distinct cs.product_id) > 1 
              THEN 'Avail' 
         END CheckAvail from grocery.vendor cs;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two queries that return the same fields but have different selection logic, you combine their results using the `UNION` operator, e.g.

```
select c1, c2 from ... where ...
union
select c1, c2 from ... where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use a [sub-select](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487138.aspx) like this

```
SELECT v.NAME,
CASE 
WHEN va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois'
  THEN 'Illinois'
END Vendors
FROM grocery.vendor v
INNER JOIN grocery.vendor_address va ON va.vendor_id = v.vendor_id
WHERE va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois' AND v.vendor_id IN (
  SELECT vendor_id FROM grocery.can_supply
  HAVING count(DISTINCT product_id) > 2
  GROUP BY vendor_id
  ORDER BY vendor_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of options here. You can do left joins (see below) exists statements, unions. CTP style pre-selects.

```
SELECT v.NAME
      , ISNULL(va.state_territory_province, '')  Vendors
      , ISNULL(inv.Desc, '') AS Desc 
FROM grocery.vendor v
LEFT JOIN grocery.vendor_address va ON va.vendor_id = v.vendor_id AND  va.state_territory_province = 'Illinois' 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT vendor_id,
             CASE WHEN count(DISTINCT product_id) > 2 THEN 'High' END AS desc
           FROM grocery.can_supply
           HAVING count(DISTINCT product_id) > 2
            GROUP BY vendor_id) inv ON inv.Vendor_Id = v.Vendor_Id 
WHERE 1=1
     AND (va.Vendor_Id NOT IS NULL OR inv.Vendor_ID NOT IS NULL)
```